# How to calculate the ratio of field and gropuby the field in Splunk

Tags: splunk

I have this table.

```
Fruits  Result
--------------
Apple   sold
Apple   sold
Apple   instock
Apple   expired
Banana  sold
Banana  sold
Banana  sold
Orange  instock
Orange  instock
```

I have to generate report like below in Splunk. I'd like to count by Fruits type and calculate the ratio of results.

```
Fruits  count  instock_ratio expired_ratio sold_ratio
----------------------------------------------------
Apple   4       0.25         0.25          0.5
Banana  3       0            0             1.0
Orange  2       1.0          0             0
```

In SQL, I can get this result.

```
WITH src AS(
    SELECT
       Fruits,
       count(CASE WHEN result="sold" THEN Fruits ELSE null END) AS sold_count,
       count(CASE WHEN result="instock" THEN Fruits ELSE null END) AS instock_count,
       count(CASE WHEN result="expired" THEN Fruits ELSE null END) AS expired_count,
       count(Fruits) AS total_counts
    FROM table
    GROUP BY Fruits
)
SELECT
   Fruits,
   total_counts,
   sold_count/total_counts,
   instock_count/total_counts,
   expired_count/total_counts
FROM src
```

Can anyone help me with the splunk command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your search

```
| stats count, count(eval(Result="sold")) AS sold_count, count(eval(Result="expired")) AS expired_count, count(eval(Result="instock")) AS instock_count by Fruits
| eval sold_ratio=sold_count/count, expired_ratio=expired_count/count, instock_ratio=instock_count/count | fields - *_count
```

We just calculate the total count and the count of each Result for each fruit. To work out the ratio, just divide each count by the total.

Here is an example that shows it works. It also uses the `foreach` command to make things cleaner.

```
| makeresults count=100 | eval r1=random()%3 | eval Fruits=case(r1=1, "Apple", r1=2, "Banana", true(), "Orange") | eval r2=random()%3 | eval Result=case(r2=1,"instock", r2=2, "sold", true(), "expired") 
| stats count, count(eval(Result="sold")) AS sold_count, count(eval(Result="expired")) AS expired_count, count(eval(Result="instock")) AS instock_count by Fruits
| foreach *_count [ eval <<MATCHSTR>>_ratio=<<FIELD>>/count ] | fields - *_count
```